# Cardinality of cartesian square

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Given an infinite set $A$ -  does the cardinality of $A$ equal to the cardinality of $A^2$?

Comment: Yes, assuming the axiom of choice.

Comment: Do you mean *group*, which is a set *with* a binary operation; or just a *set*?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/54904/).

Comment: My bad - A is a set - not group.

Comment: As a simple plausibility argument, consider the case where $A=\mathbb{R}$. Then clearly we can take the decimal expansions of two real numbers and combine them into one decimal expansion, like shuffling a pack of cards. It's also pretty easy to do an explicit construction for $\mathbb{Z}^S$, where $S$ is any set. Since we think of big sets as being built from power-sets of smaller sets, this makes it pretty plausible that it holds in general.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Zermelo proved that every well-ordered infinite set has this property, so if we assume the axiom of choice then the answer is yes. In fact the axiom of choice is equivalent to the assertion that for every infinite set $A$, $A$ and $A^2$ are equinumerous.

- The proof of Zermelo's theorem can be found here: [About a paper of Zermelo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54892/about-a-paper-of-zermelo/54904#54904)
- The proof for the reverse implication can be found here: [For every infinite $S$, $|S|=|S\times S|$ implies the Axiom of choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56466/for-every-infinite-s-s-s-times-s-implies-the-axiom-of-choice)

---

However if the axiom of choice is negated there are sets whose cardinality is strictly less of that of their square. We even know how to construct such set:

Suppose that $X$ cannot be well-ordered (such set exists, since we assume the axiom of choice is false, and therefore the well-ordering principle is false). Let $\kappa$ be an ordinal such that there is no $f\colon\kappa\to X$ which is injective.

In this case $A=X\cup\kappa$ has the property that $A^2$ is strictly larger than $A$.

Comment: You proved that $|S|=|S^2|$ implies AC, but the person asking the question is interested in proving $|S|=|S^2|$, presumably in ZFC.

Comment: @Ben: You're right, I was going to edit in the refernce to my answer from Martin's comment, but I forgot. I'll do that now.

Comment: The story about why Comptes Rendu rejected Tarski's paper is hilarious. I find the theorem surprising in that it implies full AC rather than some restricted version of choice. But I suppose the sets that violate $|A^2|=|A|$ are not explicitly constructible...?

Comment: You mean Lebesgue. That depends on what you mean constructible. I gave you a way to construct such set given a set which is not well-orderable. If the real numbers fails to be well-orderable then you can use them as the starting set.