# Can a non complete metric space be homeomorphic to its completion?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose we have a non complete metric space. Can it be homeomorphic to its metric completion?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: As a note on why completeness isn't topological by itself - http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1565350/128967

Comment: How about the sum of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ (i.e., $(\mathbb R\setminus \{0\})\times \mathbb N$)?  That is homeomorphic to its completion, which is the sum of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 post it as an answer.

Comment: There are also connected Riemannian  examples.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Just take $R^2$ minus a discrete countably infinite subset. Then modify the flat metric by rescaling via a certain function so that the new metric is complete at infinity and at each puncture except for one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the metric space $\left(\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\right)\times\mathbb Z\subset\mathbb R^2$

[image]

This metric space is not complete and its completion is $\mathbb R\times\mathbb Z$.  The two spaces are homeomorphic.  I hope that's easy to see, but here's an explicit pair of continuous inverses:

$f\;\colon\;\left(\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}\right)\times\mathbb Z\to\mathbb R\times \mathbb Z$ given by:

$$
f(x, n)=\begin{cases}
(\log(x), 2n) & x>0 \\
(\log(-x), 2n+1) & x<0
\end{cases}
$$

$g\;\colon\;\mathbb R\times\mathbb Z\to\left(\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\right)\times\mathbb Z$ given by
\begin{align}
g(y, &2k) = (e^y, k)\\
g(y, 2k&+1) = (-e^y, k)
\end{align}

You can check for yourself that these functions are continuous and that their compositions are the identity maps.

Comment: are  $f$ and $g$ continuous for the metric ? (what is the metric by the way ?)

Comment: @user1952009 The Euclidean metric.  And yes they are continuous.