# Can a metric space with a finite number of holes be homeomorphic to its completion?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a non-complete metric space. Let $\tilde X$ be its completion. Assume $\tilde X \setminus X$ is a **finite** set. (That is, $X$ has a finite number of "holes").

Is it possible for $X,\tilde X$ to be homeomorphic?

---

In general, a (non-complete) metric space [can be homeomorphic to its completion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812151/can-a-non-complete-metric-space-be-homeomorphic-to-its-completion). However, all the examples I have seen so far are with infinite number of holes. (Note that $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \dots$ actually has an infinite number of holes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Let $\tilde X$ be any infinite-dimensional Banach space, and $X=\tilde X\setminus \{0\}$. A theorem of Klee asserts that these two spaces are homeomorphic. See

1. V. Klee, *Two topological properties of topological linear spaces*, Israel J. Math. 4 (1964), 211-220.
2. K. Goebel and J. Wośko, *[Making a hole in the space](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1992-114-02/S0002-9939-1992-1065949-3/)*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 114 (1992), 475-476.

Comment: BTW, we can even remove a $\sigma$-compact subset and still have it homeomorphic (using absorbers etc.). It's a fascinating area of infinite dimensional topology.