# $(0,1) $ with the usual topology admits a metric which is complete?

Tags: general-topology, complete-spaces

Is the following statement is true?

$(0,1)$ with the usual topology admits a metric which is complete?

My answer is "False." But, the answer given is "True". I am unable to figure out. Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Do a little lateral thinking.  What complete metric space could $(0,1)$ be homeomorphic to?

Comment: @hardmath Is completeness perserved under homeomorphisms?

Comment: @Asemismaiel: Yes, if the metrics are equivalent.  Note the question asks about a selection of a metric that makes $(0,1)$ complete.  So the metric changes, but convergence is conserved by the homemorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: inspired by the [following thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1565350/why-is-completeness-not-a-topological-property), try to pull back $\mathbb{R}$ to $(0,1)$ by means of a homeomorphism. For a suitable choice, you will get a complete metric on $(0,1)$ that produces the same topology as the euclidean one.

Comment: @ Siminore : Accordinng to you, we have a metric on $(0,1)$ which induces the usual topology on $(0,1)$ which is also induced by the euclidean metric on $(0,1)$ which is not comple. so what is the appropriate answer : $(0,1)$ is complete or not with the usual topology.

Comment: Completeness is not a topological property. You should not speak of completeness in a given topology, but with a given metric.

Comment: @ Siminore : Please tell me in which metric space $(0,1)$ is complete and induce the usual topological spaces.

Comment: @Struggler you may start from the fact that $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ is homeomorphic with $\mathbb{R}$  via $x \mapsto \arctan x$.

Comment: Like $(0,1)$, is there is a metric defined on $[0,1]$ which induces the usual topology on $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]$ is incomplete.