# A cardinality number to the square is itself?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Is there a cardinal number $\kappa$ so that $\kappa \cdot \kappa$ (which is the cardinality of the set of the  Cartesian product of $\kappa$ by itself) is not equivalent to $\kappa$?

My progress: I remember learning about $Q \cdot Q$ to be $Q$, and we can prove it by the snailing technique (Q is the rationals). Then I proved the same for $R$, the real numbers (I assumed continuum cardinality).

Comment: Of course , you mean infinite cardinals. The claim would be false for finte cardinals. Your claim should be true, but I do not know how to rigorously prove it.

Comment: It is true for all infinite cardinals. There is a standard proof by transfinite induction. You can find most books on set theory or here http://planetmath.org/idempotencyofinfinitecardinals

Comment: It is true for all infinite *well-orderable* cardinals, which *would* be all infinite cardinals if the [Axiom of Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice#Equivalents) holds. In fact, $\kappa\cdot\kappa=\kappa$ holds for all infinite cardinals $\kappa$ if *and only if* the Axiom of Choice holds, as you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/180691/28900).

Answer (score 4):

The question has been answered by  Cameron Buie's comment. I wrote this answer to make it visible *at first glance* that the question is no longer open.

Cameron's comment (paraphrased):

> $A\times A \simeq A$ holds for all *well-orderable* infinite
>   sets $A$. If the [axiom of choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice#Equivalents) holds, every set is
>   well-orderable, so this means the result holds for all infinite sets. However,
>   this is not provable in the absence of choice, and in fact $A\times A\simeq A$ holds for any infinite set $A$ if and only if the axiom of
>   choice holds, as you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180671/cardinality-of-cartesian-square/180691#180691).