# If $\omega \le m^2$ then $\omega \le m$ without AC?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$m$ is a cardinal. How to prove if $\omega \le m^2$ then $\omega \le m$ without axiom of choice?

I want to construct an injection, but I am not sure how to.

Comment: If you have the axiom of choice, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2901201/a-cardinality-number-to-the-square-is-itself

Comment: Thank you for comment! I want to prove it without AC.

Comment: The word "than" is the wrong word to use. It should instead be "then".

Comment: is it true? what if we consider $\omega = m^2$ then the statement will prove AC

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi That's incorrect - you don't need AC to prove $\omega=\omega^2$ (as cardinals). Indeed, the OP's statement is provable without choice as Geoffrey Trang's answer below shows.

Comment: @Aditya In case it was missed, note $\omega$ isn't an arbitrary cardinal, which is why we cannot deduce AC from this.

Answer (score 2):

Given an infinite sequence $((a_i,b_i))_{i \ge 0}$ of distinct elements of $X \times X$ (where $X$ is a set of cardinality $m$), form the sequence $(a_0,b_0,a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,...)$. This sequence is an infinite sequence, which may, however, contain some repetitions. Let $Y$ be the set formed by the terms of this sequence (without repetitions). Then, $Y$ must be infinite, because otherwise, the sequence $((a_i,b_i))_{i \ge 0}$ would contain infinitely many distinct elements of the finite set $Y \times Y$, which is a contradiction. So, removing duplicates still gives an infinite sequence, of distinct elements of $X$ this time.