# Countable Union of sets of the same cardinality

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $A_n$ be a sequence of sets having the same cardinality $k$ (possibly uncountable, and may not be equal to the cardinality of the continuum). Also assume they are disjoint. How could I show that $\cup_n A_n$ has cardinality $k$?

Comment: I assume by the $A_n$ being countable, you specifically mean countably infinite, i.e. $|A_n| = \aleph_0$? Depending on who asks it, sometimes countable can include finite sets, which points to many counterexamples. EDIT: Then again, you might mean there are a countable number of $A_n$, so I might have totally missed the point.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462367/the-cardinality-of-an-uncountable-set-times-mathbb-n/2462381#2462381)