# Equality of Cardinality of Cartesian Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm having a hard time thinking about this problem.

My question: **Let `A` be a set. Define `C` to be the collection of all functions `f: {0,1} --> A`. Prove that `|A x A| = |C|` by constructing a bijection `F: A x A --> C`.**

I'm assuming `A x A` has the same cardinality as `A` itself. Also, to create a bijection from `A x A --> C`, I think I need to prove `|A x A|≤|C|` and `|A x A|≥|C|` through Cantor Schroder-Bernstein Theorem.

Can someone please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: "I'm assuming A x A has the same cardinality as A itself. " -- You shouldn't. This doesn't hold, for example, for finite sets.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: "I'm assuming A x A has the same cardinality as A itself. "  Well, no.   if there are $CARDINALITY$ $a_\alpha \in A$ how many $(a_\alpha, a_\beta) \in A\times A$ are there?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Oh okay. But it does hold for infinite sets like `N` right? Like, `|N x N| = |N|`?

Comment: "I think I need to prove |A x A|≤|C| and |A x A|≥|C| through Cantor Schroder-Bernstein Theorem. "  Far easier to just find the bijection itself.  A typical element of $A\times B$ would be $(a,b)$ and a typical function of $C$ would be a $f:\{0,1\} \to A$ via $f(0) = a$ and $f(1) = b$.  Can you see what would be the intended bijection?

Comment: For infinite sets ... yes and no. It (somewhat) depends on whether you assume the axiom of choice (see an elaboration [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383755/cardinality-of-the-cartesian-product-of-two-equinumerous-infinite-sets)). If you don't mind assuming the axiom of choice, though, yes: for an infinite set $S$, $|S \times S|=|S|$.

Comment: Countable Infinite?  Yes,  but that's because $|\mathbb N|^2 = |\mathbb N|$.  It's not an easy thing to prove $|\mathbb R \times \mathbb R| = |\mathbb R|$.  ... And there is *nothing* that says $A$ is infinite.

Comment: Hint:  If $f \in C$ then  $f(0)\in A$ and $f(1) \in A$ and $(f(0), f(1)) \in A\times A$.

Answer (score 1):

$C$ is a set of functions from $\{0,1\} \to A$.  A function $f\in C$ would be defined by simply spelling out what the two values of $f(0) =a$ and $f(1)=b$ are.

$A\times A$ is the set of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ where $a,b \in A$.

Can you construct a bijection.

Consider $A =\{a,b,c\}$.

Then $A\times B = \{(a,a),(a,b),(a,c), (b,a), (b,b),(b,c), (c,a), (c,b), (c,c)\}$

ANd $C = \{\{f(0)=a; f(1)=a\}, \{g(0)=a; g(1)=b\}, \{h(0)=a; h(1)=c\},etc.\}$.

Can you see the bijection between them?

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, the statement is true, because there are $|A|^2$ functions from $\{0,1\}$ to $A$-you have $|A|$ choices for $f(0)$ and again for $f(1)$.  This is independent of whether $A$ is finite or infinite.  The easiest approach is not through C-S-B but to directly construct the isomorphism.  If I give you an $f$, what element of $C$ is it natural to pair with it?