# $A$ and $B$ are infinite sets, is it true that the cardinality of its Cartesian product ($|A×B|$) is equal to max $(|A|,|B|)$?

Tags: logic, set-theory, cardinals

If $A$ and $B$ are infinite sets, is it true that the cardinality of its Cartesian product ($|A \times B|$) is equal to max $(|A|,|B|)$? If it is true, why? (We assume the axiom of choice)

Comment: With axiom of choice it is true in case of $A=B$.

Comment: It is true if we assume the axiom of choice; see **MikeMathMan**’s answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383755/cardinality-of-the-cartesian-product-of-two-equinumerous-infinite-sets?rq=1). It also implies the axiom of choice; see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56466/for-every-infinite-s-s-s-times-s-implies-the-axiom-of-choice?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me please if I'm not right.

1. $|A \times B|  \geq \max (|A|,|B|)$
2. $ |A \cup B| = \max (|A|, |B|)$
3. $| (A \cup B) \times (A \cup B)| = |A \cup B|  = \max (|A|, |B|)$
4. $|A \times B| \leq | (A \cup B) \times (A \cup B)| = \max (|A|, |B|)$
5. $\max (|A|, |B|) \leq |A \times B| \leq \max (|A|, |B|)$

then $|A \times B| = \max (|A|, |B|)$

Comment: The claim that $|(A\cup B)\times(A\cup B)|=|A\cup B|$ (and more generally, that for an infinite set $C$, $C\times C$ is bijectable with $C$, is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice (theorem of Tarski)