# Bijection between an infinite set and the sets of all its finite sequences

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $X$ be an infinite set. Then it is provable (I believe) that 
$$|X| = |\{(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \mid n ∈ \mathbb{N}, x_i ∈ X\}|.$$
Without resorting to abstract results in set theory, can we find a bijection that makes this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an inherently vague question, but there is a precise result which indicates that the answer is **no**. Specifically, it is consistent with [ZF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) (= set theory with the [Axiom of Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice)) that there are infinite sets for which that equality *fails*. Indeed, the mere statement "For all infinite sets $X$, we have $X\equiv X^2$" [is equivalent to](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56466/for-every-infinite-s-s-s-times-s-implies-the-axiom-of-choice) the axiom of choice.

So without knowing anything else about $X$, we can't be sure the result holds unless we accept the axiom of choice, and if that's not "abstract set theory" I don't know what is.

---

That said, for some infinite sets we *can* do this. For example, taking $X=\mathbb{N}$ we can use prime factorization: consider the map $$\langle x_1,...,x_n\rangle\mapsto p_1^{x_1+1}\cdot ...\cdot p_n^{x_n+1},$$ where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime (the "$+1$" superscript is to handle the case when $x_i=0$ - if you don't consider $0$ a natural number, you don't need it). It's easy to show that this is an injection. With this in mind it's not hard to exhibit and verify a concrete *bijection* if you don't want to use Cantor-Bernstein. (And there are plenty of other ways to do this too.)

It's a good exercise at this point to come up with an explicit injection from the set of all finite sequences of *real* numbers into $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was too quick. In fact my $X$ is an infinite _ring_, but I thought I could generalise it. I accept AC, and can work with it somewhat. I suppose a similar thing could be done with the prime elements of the ring then? Or can infinite rings contain only finitely many prime elements? Then I suppose it doesn't work anymore.