# If $A$ is any infinite set, is $A × A$ equivalent/equinumerous to $A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

I know the result is true for $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ and can even be generalized for $\mathbb{N^n}$ and $\mathbb{R^n}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but I'm not sure how I can prove this for an arbitrary infinite set $A$ (I'm assuming it's true, but can't provide any proof of this claim). This came up while I was trying to solve some other question, but I'm stuck now.

Any help, feedback or even a solution is much appreciated.

Comment: this doesn't always hold, but is equivalent to the axiom of choice. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski's_theorem_about_choice

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/56466/81360) as well

Comment: The statement holds if you assume the Axiom of Choice (in fact, it is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice; this is a [theorem of Tarski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_theorem_about_choice).

Comment: To complement the comment of @peabrainiac: This does always hold, because it's equivalent to the axiom of choice. The point is that the meaning of  "always" depends on what axiom system you're working in.