# Help with proof of equivalence of $AC$ and $|S|=|S \times S| $ for all $S$.

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I’m going through the proof by Asaf that $|S|=|S \times S|$ for all infinite $S$ implies the Axiom of Choice, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/56471).
I’m not understanding 100% of it and wondering if I could get some help. I'm self studying set theory and still learning...! Some of the confusion comes about because I am not that familiar with ZF and there is not a lot online about it.

- Although not in the proof, is it true that under ZF if $A,B$ are not well-orderable then $|A|=|B| ⇔A≈B$.

The forwards direction is obvious, but I can’t get the reverse (although I don’t think it is required in any event).

- Whenever it is stated “let $κ$ be an infinite cardinal” does this mean that $κ$ is infinite and either it is the least ordinal equinumerous to some well-orderable set or it is the set of all sets equinumerous to some set that cannot be well-ordered and that are of minimal rank?
- Looking at the main theorem part, it is shown that if $κ$ is an infinite cardinal, then it must be well orderable.
  The direct conclusion that if $A$ is an infinite set then it is well orderable is not given. But I guess if we assume that $A$ is an infinite set and $κ=|A|$ then because $κ$ is well orderable, $|κ|=κ$ and so $|A|=|κ|$ and so $A≈κ$ and $A$ is well orderable.
- For the inequality part, I assume that we use the definition of cardinal arithmetic irrespective of if the cardinal is an initial ordinal or it is generated via Scott’s trick? In which case:

By our assumption, $|κ+ℵ(κ)|=|(κ+ℵ(κ))$ x $(κ+ℵ(κ))|$. And by definition $(κ+ℵ(κ)).(κ+ℵ(κ))=|(κ+ℵ(κ)$ x $(κ+ℵ(κ)|$. Expanding out $|κ+ℵ(κ)|≥κ.ℵ(κ)≥κ+ℵ(κ)$. But because $|κ|≠ κ$ for a cardinal $κ$ that cannot be well-ordered, how do we turn $|κ+ℵ(κ)|$ into $κ+ℵ(κ)$ and then conclude $κ+ℵ(κ)=κ.ℵ(κ)$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, avoid the use of uncommon characters in MathJax. Use `\aleph`, `\kappa`, `\approx`, `iff`, `\ge` for $\aleph$, $\kappa$, $\approx$, $\iff$, $\ge$. Also use `\times` for $\times$

Comment: Yes, I write my answers in word and paste them in. It used to paste the latex; I'll have to see what I am doing wrong!

Comment: Ok, I didn't know Word can do that (or used to)

Answer (score 1):

The use of $\kappa$ in that answer is perhaps a bit misleading (and I have stopped using $\kappa$ for general cardinal notation, although some of my coauthors still do that).

The idea that a cardinal is inherently an ordinal is somewhat limiting when working in a choiceless context. We can instead of a cardinal as a representation of the equivalence class of all sets which are in bijection with $A$. This can be a member of this equivalence class, or it can just be some abstract representative (traditionally, Scott cardinals for sets which are not well-orderable).

But the important thing is that the concept is a well-defined one, and that we can use the term cardinal to talk about cardinality of any set. Not just well-ordered ones.

Indeed, in the case of a well-ordered set, we already have the Gödel pairing function which provides us a bijection with its square, and therefore we do not need the Axiom of Choice for proving that.

Comment: So, in ZFC we say k is a cardinal number of A if k is the least ordinal equinumerous to A, and k is a cardinal if it is the cardinal number of some set. In ZF do we extend this definition of cardinal to also include any set that can be generated from some other set using Scott’s trick?

Comment: Yeah. That is generally what we do.

Comment: I’m just wondering if the cardinal arithmetic identities hold under this new definition (as it seems many of the proofs depend on the cardinality of a cardinal number is itself). For example, does distributivity hold? I’ll check it out later today as well.

Comment: Well, I've tweaked the proof so that it now doesn't use cardinality, any mention of, or allusion to, Scott's trick or any cardinal arithmetic. It's a tricky proof and thanks for Asaf's exposition. If anyone would like a more detailed proof, I'm happy to update this post with an edit (hopefully it will help..).