# Application of Cantor-Bernstein Theorem?

Tags: set-theory

This is a problem in " Basic set theory "- S.Shen: prove that if $ [0,1]=A \cup B$ then either $A$ or $B$ has the cardinality of the continuum. (Does this follow from the Cantor-Bernstein theorem?)

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1679433/a-cup-b-mathfrakc-then-a-or-b-has-cardinality-mathfrakc).

Comment: @bof I thought   this problem in a  week but I counld'nt understand  how does it work in closed unit interval?
Could you explain for me?

Comment: @bof I can't understand what is horizontal line in the real line?

Comment: **(1)** Do you understand that there is a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]\times[0,1]$? **(2)** Do you understand that, if $h:[0,1]\to[0,1]\times[0,1]$ is a bijection, and if $[0,1]=A\cup B,$ then $[0,1]\times[0,1]=h(A)\cup h(B)$? **(3)** Do you understand why it follows, as in the solution to that other question, that either $h(A)$ or $h(B)$ has the cardinality of the continuum? **(4)** And why it follows from that, that $A$ or $B$ has the cardinality of the continuum?

Comment: thanks a lot @bof . I understand it now.