# Cardinality of integral domain equals cardinality of its field of quotients?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Let $D$ be an integral domain and $F$ be its field of quotients. Let $[(x, y)]$ denote the equivalence class of $(x, y)$. If $D$ is finite, then $D \simeq F$, so $|D| = |F|$. If $D$ is infinite, then the function mapping from $D$ to $F$ given by $d \mapsto [(d, 1)]$ is an injection. But what function is an injection from $F$ to $D$? I know there is an injection from $F$ to $D \times D$ given by $[(p, q)] \mapsto (p, q)$, but is there an injection from $D \times D$ to $D$? Is it even true that $|F| = |D|$ in this case?

Is it true that $|S \times S| = |S|$ for any infinite set $S$? If any of these are true, where could I find a proof?

Comment: It can be proved that $|S \times S| = |S|$ for any infinite $S$ if one assumes the axiom of choice.You could have a look at the Wikipedia page on [cardinal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_multiplication) and the links therein.

Comment: For the squaring of an infinite cardinal, see [this previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660884/for-every-infinite-cardinal-kappa-kappa2-kappa).

Answer (score 1):

Let us write

$$\pi_1: \begin{cases}D\times D\to F\\(a,b)\mapsto [(a,b)]\end{cases}\\ \\
\pi_2:\begin{cases}F\to D\\ a/b\mapsto a\end{cases}$$

We have

$$D\times D\overset{\pi_1}{\twoheadrightarrow}F\overset{\pi_2}{\twoheadrightarrow} D$$
(Here the double headed arrows are used to represent surjections) Switching to cardinalities:

$$|D\times D|\ge |F|\ge |D|$$

As it has been proved by Tarski (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54892/about-a-paper-of-zermelo/54904#54904) for a proof and an historical digression), AC is equivalent to

$$|D\times D|=|D|$$

Thus we obtain

$$|D|\ge |F|\ge |D|$$

which implies, thanks to [Schröder-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem?wprov=sfla1)

$$|D|=|F|$$