# Non-simple homogeneous components of a module.

Tags: modules

Let $M_R$ be a right $R$-module. A **homogeneous component** $H$ of $M_R$ is defined to be the sum $\sum_{i\in I}B_i$ where $\lbrace B_i \rbrace_{i\in I}$ is a family of mutually isomorphic simple submodules $B_i \subseteq M$. Is it true that if the homogeneous component $H$ is non-simple then $H$ is decomposable as $H=N\oplus K$ or $H=N \oplus K \oplus L$ where $N\cong K$ and $L$ is simple?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

$H$ is semisimple by definition, so you can write it as $\oplus_{i\in I}H_i$ for some index set $I$ and all the $H_i$'s are mutually isomorphic and simple.

Then either

1. $H$ has finite composition length and it is

   1. even, in which case $N$ and $K$ are a sum of half the composition length copies of the simple module or
   2. odd, in which case you split off one copy $L$ of the simple module and divide the rest into two equal groups to get $N$ and $K$; or
2. $H$ does not have finite composition length, in which case you can just [divide the index set into two equipotent pieces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660884/for-every-infinite-cardinal-kappa-kappa2-kappa) and use them to find $K$ and $N$.

Comment: This is what I have thought of. But I have two questions. Question 1: Where is the use of the hypothesis that $H$ is non-simple ?!. Question 2: What is the guarantee that the sum $N + K$ is direct (In other world, how to guarantee that $N \cap K = 0$ ?!).

Comment: @HusseinEid 1) I don’t see any use for it. It first the second case when $N=K=\{0\}$.  2) the homogeneous component is semisimple by definition, so you can always express it as a direct sum of simples.