# Prove that $b\cdot\aleph_0=b$, where b is an infinite set.

Tags: set-theory

Prove that $b\cdot\aleph_0=b$, where $b$ is an infinite set.
I tried by multiplying $1\le\aleph_0\le b$ with $b$ but then I have to prove that $b\cdot b=b$
 and that seems harder than my original problem.

Comment: The usual approach is to use Zorn to show that each infinite set is a disjoint union of infinite countable subsets.

Comment: I think the usual approach would actually be to prove that $bb=b$, which in turn can be proved by supplying $b\times b$ with a nice well-ordering which can only be of order type $b$ (by induction on $b$)

Comment: For the proof of $b^2=b$ you can have a look at the answer posted here: [About a paper of Zermelo](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54892). Some of [other post linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/54892) might be of interest, too.