# Is there an intuitive way of justifying why the square of an infinite cardinal is itself?

Tags: set-theory, intuition, cardinals

By no means I am an expert in this subject, but I do have some knowledge of ZFC. While there are many proofs which are difficult to recollect, I feel like I have enough knowledge that if I am given a statement about ordinals or cardinals, then I can prove it myself. However, there is one particular thing which didn't seem intuitive to me at all and whose proof is also difficult to remember or recreate, which is:

> If $\kappa$ is any infinite cardinal, then $\kappa\cdot\kappa = \kappa$.

Does anyone know of an intuitive proof of this? The fact that $\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0 = \aleph_0$ is very intuitive, because this is just saying that cartesian product of two countable sets is countable. If $c = |\mathbb{R}|$, then the fact that $c\cdot c = c$ is also more or less intuitive: that $|(0 , 1)| = c$, we can use decimal expansions of numbers to justify this.

Can we visualise this fact somehow, or if not do you know of seeing this more easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're wrong about $\aleph_0$. The fact that the product of two countable sets is countable is not "the intuitive reason" for $\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0=\aleph_0$. It is the very definition of the equality. You've merely recast the symbols into words. It only becomes intuitive once you've seen the proof a few times.

The general fact that $\kappa\cdot\kappa=\kappa$ for any infinite cardinal is equivalent to the axiom of choice, so we may as well assume it. In this case, the intuition is *sort of* the same from the case of $\aleph_0$: we can order the set $\kappa\times\kappa$ in a well-order satisfying the property that every proper initial segment has size $<\kappa$. Much like how we order $\Bbb{N\times N}$ in a way that every proper initial segment is finite.

If you want to talk about sets like $\Bbb R$, then you can actually talk about this without the axiom of choice: if $A$ is an infinite set and $|A\times\{0,1\}|=|A|$, then we can use a bijection witnessing that to prove that $|\mathcal P(A)\times\mathcal P(A)|=|\mathcal P(A)|$. Since the real numbers satisfy $|\Bbb R|=|\mathcal P(\Bbb N)|$, the result follows. Alternatively, you can verify that for any set $X$, setting $A=X^\Bbb N$, we have $|A\times A|=|A|$, and again apply this to $X=\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb{|R|=|N^N|}$.

Or, more generally, if $|A\times\{0,1\}|=|A|$, then $|X^A\times X^A|=|X^A|$ for any set $X$.

But now we see why "intuitive" is the wrong term here. This is not true for every infinite set without assuming the axiom of choice: if AC fails, not every infinite set can be well-ordered, and certainly not every infinite set is a power set, or equipotent to a set of the form $X^A$ with the needed properties.

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that you’ve previously described one such well-order on $\kappa\times\kappa$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54892/about-a-paper-of-zermelo/).

Comment: And elsewhere, to be honest. I've answered *a lot* of questions on this topic. :P

Comment: Yep; that just happened to be the one that turned up first.