# Does there exist an equivalence relation on a set such that the set of equivalence classes and all individual equivalence classes are all uncountable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

I have thought about many examples, usually involving equivalence relations on $\Bbb{R}$, and so far none of them fulfill the criteria. I have tried to think about the various definitions of equivalence relation, equivalence classes, countability and so on but I have yet to prove or disprove it for sure. At this point I feel like there exists no such equivalence relation, but I would like to know for sure and how you would go about proving this.

Comment: On $\mathbb R^2$, let $(x,y)\sim(x’,y’)$ iff $(y=y’)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a general approach to this, note that if we are assuming the axiom of choice, then every infinite set $S$ has the same cardinality as $S\times S$ (proving this is a little more complicated, you can find more info [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54892/about-a-paper-of-zermelo/54904#54904)). Thus there exists a bijection $f:S\rightarrow S\times S$, and we can construct an equivalence relation such that $x\sim y$ if and only the first part of $f(x)$ equals the first part of $f(y)$. If $S$ is uncountable, this equivalence relation has the properties you want.

A similar result without choice seems possible, but is probably more complex if it exists.