# If $|A| = |A_1| = |A_2|$ holds for infinite sets $A, A_1$ and $A_2$ where $A_1 \cap A_2 = \emptyset$, is it true that $|A| = |A_1 \cup A_2|?$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

For some reason, I think this is true. I suppose it is clear why $|A| \leq |A_1 \cup A_2|$. I wonder if there's a way to show the existence of an injection $\phi: A_1 \cup A_2 \to A$.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @lulu Sorry, I forgot to mention that these sets have to be infinite obviously. My bad.

Comment: no worries. $\quad$

Comment: [Tarski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_theorem_about_choice) showed that "$S$ is always in bijection with $S\times S$" (for infinite $S$) is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice.  Of course that implies your result, though perhaps one can get there without AOC.

Comment: Alas, no:  [Amorphous sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set) can be constructed if you drop choice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [About a paper of Zermelo](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54892/about-a-paper-of-zermelo) Even $A\times A$ is as big as $A$, for $2A$ it then follows from [Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schröder–Bernstein_theorem).

Comment: Thank you guys. Your comments have been very helpful. I understand the answer now.